# Oracle 11g Rows into Columns Dynamically

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, pivot-table

I dont know how to convert column values into rows dynamically in Oracle 11g, please help on this.

I have attached input and expected output values in the screenshot.

[image]

here rollno is uniq value for each row, based on the rollno,can populate the distinct marks into columns [it may come dynamically or upto 5 columns as denoted in picture] and the same way need to populate the distinct class values [can populate dynamically or upto 5 columns]

Comment: Unfortunately, this can't be solved completely as is. You have not specified your constraints clearly enough. Specifically, under rollno 101, what makes marks 101 and marks1 104? And why no marks2 there? Do they have to be in separate columns, or do they just need to be on a single line grouped by rollno?

Comment: I think I figured out what you are really after. See my answer. If I am off, I will adjust it accordingly.

Comment: Hi Sandiper, I have updated the constraint in the requirement, please help on this

Comment: I still direct you to my answer. The problem is that marks1, marks2 etc don't mean anything. You have just ordered them into a row. There is nothing unique that means that in the second row marks2 will always be 104. If you had other values then 104 would shift to the right. That makes this a bad application for PIVOT.

Comment: The deeper question you should answer is WHY do you need these in different columns?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you really want a pivot in this case. Specifically because you don't seem to have concrete columns shared by all groups for `marks` and `class`. It seems that what you REALLY want is this information listed nice and neat in one row. In that case, you should use the LISTAGG() function. Try this:

```
SELECT rollno, 
       LISTAGG(marks, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY marks) AS marks_list,
       LISTAGG(class, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY class) AS class_list
FROM my_table
GROUP BY rollno
ORDER BY rollno
```

More information on LISTAGG() can be found [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions089.htm#SQLRF30030).

Answer (score 0):

The below query giving the result as expected

WITH T1 AS(

select ROLLNO

```
 , (select listagg(column_value, ',') within group (order by column_value ASC) from table(collect_col2)) as marks_list




 , (select listagg(column_value, ',') within group (order by column_value ASC) from table(collect_col3)) as class_list
```

from

(select ROLLNO,   collect(distinct MARKS) as collect_col2 , collect(distinct CLASS) as collect_col3 from STUDENT group by ROLLNO))

SELECT rollno,REGEXP_SUBSTR(marks_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 1,NULL,1) marks1,REGEXP_SUBSTR(marks_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 2,NULL,1) marks2,REGEXP_SUBSTR(marks_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 3,NULL,1) marks3,REGEXP_SUBSTR(marks_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 4,NULL,1) marks4,

REGEXP_SUBSTR(marks_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 5,NULL,1) marks5,REGEXP_SUBSTR(marks_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 6,NULL,1) marks6,REGEXP_SUBSTR(class_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 1,NULL,1) class1,REGEXP_SUBSTR(class_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 2,NULL,1) class2,

REGEXP_SUBSTR(class_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 3,NULL,1) class3,

REGEXP_SUBSTR(class_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 4,NULL,1) class4,

REGEXP_SUBSTR(class_list, '([^,]*)(,|$)', 1, 5,NULL,1) class5

FROM T1